# 12.04 wholly dark Ambiance theme?

Tags: 12.04, themes, appearance, ambiance

I got my first partition of Ubuntu recently, and wanted to match it to a 10 or 11 interface I was using on another computer. It looked like this:

[image]

Themes in 12.04 seem to be rather tricky though. I've delved into `usr/share/themes` and `~/`. Themes countless times with gtk-2 and gtk-3 trying to get things working, using Appearance and Advanced Settings (from a "tweak" something or other). Nothing has worked though, and the themes I've found so far are ugly to boot. All I'm looking for is straight up Ambiance with dark backgrounds for *everything* but that seems out of reach. Any advice?

Comment: That looks like the all-dark variant of Ambiance which was in development during the Maverick cycle until it was canceled sometime before release. Officially, it's no longer available, so a third-party solution would be required here.

Comment: Taking a theme and darkening it nearly everywhich way I can is a favorite hobby of mine. If you ask the same question over at ubuntuforums.org we can go back and forth in a less restrictive manner. In case it isn't clear, I've darkened Ambiance so thoroughly that its makers would be ashamed to be associated with it ;)

Comment: please visit [Radiance theme customization in Ubuntu: edit Window decorator and all!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406840/radiance-theme-customization-in-ubuntu-edit-window-decorator-and-all) to see if there's anything that could help.. I've not played with the _"shade"_ values but you could try them too..

Answer (score 2):

I've created my own Ambiance Dark theme, however I've darkened it quite a bit, if you are interested it can be found here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+Dark?content=147513

Here is a screenshot of my theme with Nautilus and Geany open on Ubuntu 13.10
[image: Screenshot of theme with Nautilus and Geany open]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Dark theme similar to Ambiance but not Ambiance,  called as [OMG_Suite](http://nale12.deviantart.com/art/OMG-Suite-288398137). On my system it currently looks as

[image]

And the Right click menu as

[image]

And also refer the [Reintroduced Dark Ambiance theme](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/06/dark-ambiance-reintroduces-dark-touches-to-ubuntus-default-theme).

Answer (score 1):

The [elementary Dark - GTK3 Theme](http://satya164.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d41fakm) is another dark theme and comes with its own ppa.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you might looking for: (GTK 3 version of Ambiance Dark theme, which was made by Canonical for Ubuntu 10.10, but wasn't included in final release)

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=161649

Screenshot (MATE desktop) :

[image: Screenshot]