# Radiance theme customization in Ubuntu: edit Window decorator and all!

Tags: themes

As you can see in the snapshot below I've made quite a few changes in the Radiance theme, from dusty brown to silver, Alice Blue tool-tip background, among other changes (by editing some files in `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/*`). But I couldn't manage to change the window decorator colour. How can I change that *(preferably by editing the configuration files)*?

[image: snap1]

#### Edit:

Almost all fixed but the Chromium Web Browser's tab bar! Ideas?!
[image: snap2]

Comment: I think that depends on your window manager, probably **Metacity**.

Comment: @vasa1, I have Precise as my system and I am using Unity 3d with compiz as the WM..

Comment: Yes, but please look in /usr/share/themes/Radiance and see if you have a Metacity folder. (I'm on 13.10 and run Openbox so I'm just guessing.)

Comment: oh right.. I'll try making changes there.. thanks..

Comment: @vasa1 that worked great! thank you once again..

Comment: @hash ^^ you could make an answer describing what you did.

Comment: @vasa1, okay I thought the job was done but it seems we're almost there.. I've managed to change the window decorator colour too but Chromium browser's tab bar still resists to change! any ideas with that?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by Chromium browser's tab bar but please look in your gtkrc for a section on Chromium (with `style "chrome-gtk-frame"`) or for a separate file called chromium.rc in your gtk2 folder. The relevant changes should be possible there. Keep in mind that Chromium is relatively "locked down" in its appearance and you won't be able to change everything you want.

Comment: @vasa1, ..really thankful for all your help. I made the changes in the `chromium.rc` file and that gave me what I wanted. Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

It was that I missed to make some edits in the files `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`; which I edited to specify the colours that I wanted for the windows decorator. *(But still unable to fix the colour of tab-bar of the Chromium browser.)*

Altogether I've made changes in the files:

`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`,

`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`,

`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`,

`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`, and

`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/apps/chromium.rc`

Here's a snapshot of my custom colour palette which includes most of the changes that I made in the colour values in the files mentioned above:

[image: snap1]
<sup>(Note: the info_fg_color and info_bg_color values shown above is not a very good match.)</sup>

This is what my Ubuntu desktop with the modified *Radiance* theme looks like:

[image: snap2]

#### Edit: *"...all fixed but the Chromium Web Browser's tab bar!"* [solved]

To modify *ChromeGtkFrame* (which I referred to as Chromium Web Browser's tab bar) colour changes had to be made in the `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/apps/chromium.rc` file; where I used the colour value `#e2e2e2`. Here's what Chromium window now looks like:

[image: snap3]

---

Courtesies to the helpful comments/answers from [vasa1](https://askubuntu.com/users/25656) for getting the problem is fixed.

Comment: re. Chrome, I'm sure you've noticed the scrollbar bit as well: you could play with values there if you want a little more contrast between the thumb (the part we drag up/down/) and the trough.