# Add another layout in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I want to type in Hindi in Lubuntu, so I can use it in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Adding and using a Keyboard Layout:

Click the keyboard icon at the panel and select keyboard layout settings or select ***System Settings -> Keyboard Layout***:
[image: kl01]

Click the add (<kbd>**+**</kbd>) icon, search for the preferred language layout like *hindi*, *nepali*, or others input, select and hit <kbd>**Add**</kbd> button.
[image: kl02]

Click the keyboard icon at the top panel select the layout you want to use. You can [toggle the layout with the keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414269/hold-a-key-to-temporarily-switch-keyboard-layout/418176#418176): <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**Caps Lock**</kbd>
[image: kl03]

Snapshot of Hindi (Bolnagari) keyboard layout:
[image: snapKBL]

---

*Useful link:*

- [How to assign shortcut keys to quickly switch between keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414269/hold-a-key-to-temporarily-switch-keyboard-layout/418176#418176)

Comment: What themes are you using?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, I use my customized Radiance theme.. more at [Radiance theme customization in Ubuntu: edit Window decorator and all!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406840/radiance-theme-customization-in-ubuntu-edit-window-decorator-and-all) and together with that I've also changed the window buttons in `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/metacity-1` and `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity`.. the icon-theme which I use is Moka...