# Theme identification (ubuntu 11.10) and file location unknown!

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gtk

[image]

Where can I find the directory and files, related to the theme above, which I believe is part of KDE (but I am not to sure about that)?!

I'd like to make some changes, just like:

- Integrating some, but not all applications (that use the current theme as shown in the screen shot) to my standard and preferred dark GTK theme.
- Changing the `highlight bar`, button-`prelight` + `pressed` and `scrollbar` color.
- Making some pictographic and/or code based changes, related to button and tab-shading, the scrollbar, roundness of single elements etc..

**Applications, that use the same theme:**

- Synaptic Package Manager
- Geany
- Gimp
- and others..

Any pointer in the right direction is highly appreciated! --thanks!

---

**Edit:** I already use gnome-tweak-tool, gconf & dconf editor, to customize and setup themes, fonts, icons etc. but in this case to no avail. I also know, where themes and icons are located on my system, but I can't figure it out for the theme in question. It is no Qt3/Qt4 Theme either!

[image]
[image]

Thank you for your answer so far.

Comment: why have you labelled this 11.10 - is this the version of ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Ubuntu Tweak, which gives easy interface to tweak desktop and system
 configuration available under *utils* section in *Precise*.

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

[image: snap1]

Or you could use **Dconf editor** (install with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`). In *Precise* it's available under *universe/libs* section.

[image: snap2]

---

And you can find the themes and their configuration files in `/usr/share/themes`. There under the target theme directory, you can edit the configuration files (like the ones in `gtk-2.0`, `gtk-3.0` directories) to suit your need.

<sub>[Reference: Radiance theme customization in Ubuntu: edit Window decorator and all!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406840/radiance-theme-customization-in-ubuntu-edit-window-decorator-and-all)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer rusty. The `.gtkrc`, `.rc` and `.ini` files mentioned in your provided link are worth taking a closer look of. I also added more information to my question.

Comment: @v2r if you're looking to make theme changes to specific applications, maybe you'll have to edit/create app specific `*.css` or `*.rc` files in the target theme..